# iOS6 UITableView section header duplicates

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios6

I have an UITableView with expandable rows in section 4. When one row is expanded the others need to be collapsed. I reload specified rows and scroll table to have the expanded one on top. Here's the code:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

        if (indexPath.section == 4)
        {
            if (indexPath.row == 0)
            {
                if (hypoExpanded)
                {
                    hypoExpanded = NO;

                    [self performSelector:@selector(reloadRowWithScrollForIndexPath:) withObject:indexPath afterDelay:kAnimationDelay];
                }
                else
                {
                    hypoExpanded = YES;
                    moodExpanded = NO;
                    activityExpanded = NO;

                    NSArray *indexArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:4], [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:4], nil];
                    [self performSelector:@selector(reloadRowWithScrollForIndexArray:) withObject:indexArray afterDelay:kAnimationDelay];
                } 

    ... }
}

- (void)reloadRowWithScrollForIndexArray:(NSArray *)indexArray
    {
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:((NSIndexPath *)[indexArray objectAtIndex:0]).row inSection:((NSIndexPath *)[indexArray objectAtIndex:0]).section] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    }


- (void)reloadRowWithScrollForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    }


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    switch (section)
    {
        case 1:
            return [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgc-info"]];
            break;

        case 2:
            return [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"in-info"]];
            break;

        case 3:
            return [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bp-info"]];
            break;

        case 4:
            return [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"per-info"]];
            break;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Sometimes a random section header (1, 2 or 3) duplicates and overlays the cell that belongs to that section. Scrolling the table to make the section disappear doesn't help. When I scroll back the duplicated header still exists. 
It only happens on iOS 6. Invoking performSelectorOnMainThread: is not helpful either. Also, without calling scrollToRowAtIndexPath: everything works fine. What could possibly cause this behaviour?

You can see a screenshot here:

[image]

Comment: put titleForHeaderInSection method

Comment: I added viewForHeaderInSection implementation to my question. I did not implemented titleForHeaderInSection method. I had to edit the screenshot so the images are not visible.

Comment: so how can u display section 1,2,... ??

Comment: see edited my comment above

Comment: i ran into the exact same issue - did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: I have the same problem, any solution found?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Check for uncommitted animation in your code

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
... should be committed below
```